# jquery ajax progress only shows 100%

Tags: jquery, ajax, file-upload, progress-bar, progress

I use the ajaxuploader.js to upload pictures.

i use the following piece of code to get the progress of the ajax request:

```
 jQuery(function($) {
    $.ajaxUploadSettings.name = 'uploads[]';
    $('#pic-upload-area').ajaxUploadPrompt({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "myUrl",
        beforeSend: function() {
           // do sth
        },
        error: function(data) {
           // do sth
        },
        success: function(data) {
            // do sth
        },
        xhrFields: {
            onprogress: function(progress) {
                var percentage = Math.floor((progress.total / progress.totalSize) * 100);
                console.log('progress', percentage);
                if (percentage === 100) {
                    console.log('DONE!');
                }
            }
        },
    });
});
```

Seems to work, at the ende it logs "process 100" and "DONE!".

But whats with the percentages between 0 and 100? Seems the eventlistener doesnt work properly and fires evry x ms and gets me the current percentage of the upload.

Comment: Maybe your upload is short enough that it finishes before there are any percentages to display.

Comment: I had this exact problem and found my answer here 

[Can onprogress functionality be added to jQuery.ajax() by using xhrFields?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15668339/can-onprogress-functionality-be-added-to-jquery-ajax-by-using-xhrfields

Comment: I have the same trouble. Finally I figured out the reason is I'm using the local server, so it uploads file too fast to fire more than one `onprogress` event.