# jquery ajax combine xhrFields onprogress and error together

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Can I combine the ajax xhrFields onprogress and error settings?  I am sending progress informartion as I am reading 1 .. n results files to create an excel spreadsheet xlsx, create charts, finalizing workbooks and finally saving the xlsx file.

- If I raise an error in PHP the error: handles everything properly as long as I have not sent the first onprogress message

  - The jqXHR.responseJSON or jqXHR.responseText **exists**
- If I first send an onprogress message and then raise an error the error: has a problem

  - The jqXHR.responseJSON or jqXHR.responseText **does not exists**

```
    $.ajax({
        type    : "POST",
        url     : "/?route=ajax",
        data    : {
            request : 'processing/ProcessAssayDataController@processRequest',
            requestId: requestId,
            token   : $("#csrfToken").val()
        },
        beforeSend : function(jqXHR, settings) {
           // Actions to take before call, works great
        },
        xhrFields: {
            onprogress: function (e) {
            // This is working great
             },
        },
        success : function (data) {
           // Actions to take on success, works great
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           // See notes on how this is not working
        },
        complete: function (data) {
           // Actions to take after call is complete, works great

        },
        timeout: 0,  // Needed because I am generating a large spreadsheet
    });
```

Comment: see if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15668339/can-onprogress-functionality-be-added-to-jquery-ajax-by-using-xhrfields